# Как отличить определяемое слово от приложения？

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Как определить, что является определяемым словом, а что приложением？

> Толстый кучер（,）Яким, кроткий человек, ласково и робко успокаивает коней

Поставила запятую после «кучер», т.к. посчитала, что «кучер» — определяемое слово, а «Якимє» — приложение, и перед ним можно поставить *а именно*, *то есть*, *а зовут его* — и выделила запятыми. Но это ошибка, и определяемое слово в этом предложении «Яким». Приложение «толстый кучер» стоит перед опр. словом и не имеет дополнительного обст. значения, значит запятыми не выделяется.

Как тут не запутаться и точно узнать, что является определяемым словом, а что приложением？

Answer (score 2):

При составлении текста возможны **варианты**, которые определяются содержанием и структурой предложения, также это может быть **авторским решением.**

(1) Толстый кучер Яким, **кроткий человек**, ласково и робко успокаивает коней.

В этом предложении уже есть обособленное приложение ***кроткий человек***, поэтому еще одно обособление **нежелательно**.   *Яким* — определяемое слово (подлежащее). *Толстый кучер* — распространенное приложение.

(2) При отсутствии обособленного приложения:

**Толстый кучер, Яким,  ласково и робко успокаивает коней.**

(Или: Толстый кучер Яким   ласково и робко успокаивает коней. Обособление здесь факультативное).

Теперь *кучер* — это определяемое слово, оно же является подлежащим. А *имя* — это обособленное приложение со значением уточнения.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем со второго предложения. Обычно имя собственное является определяемым словом:

**Толстый кучер Яким ласково и робко успокаивает коней.**

Но в конечном итоге все зависит от контекста и воли автора. Если главное в этом сообщении то, что толстый кучер успокаивает коней, а его имя дается как бы попутно, то:

**Толстый кучер, Яким, ласково и робко успокаивает коней.**

Что касается первого предложения, то имя Яким и его характеристика "кроткий человек" не могут быть поставлены в ряд через запятую как однородные приложения к "толстому кучеру" (нет между ними однородности). Остается один вариант:

**Толстый кучер Яким, кроткий человек, ласково и робко успокаивает коней.**